# web api support parameters while they don't have one

Tags: asp.net-web-api

http://localhost:xxxx/api/BindAppointmentResources
 works fine for me but when I'm trying to add any invalid object after controller (with this ? "http://localhost:xxxxx/api/BindAppointmentResources?Userid") in URL its gets the same result

I tried action-based routing , attribute routing so far but same result?

PS : I don't have parameters in WEB API

Route Config :

```
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Add your route config and controller.

Comment: @RahulJyala Clerify your problem please its your first question try to see some details for asking question .stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: @HeemanshuBhalla sir , while adding parameter I want an error because I don't have parameter  but does not get any error showing the same result before it seems like issue

Comment: @SefaÜmitOray my controller BindAppointmentResources  and route config I didn't change anything its default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query string parameters will automatically get bound to your parameters that have the same name in web api. 
If no parameter names are found it will route the request to the base url (which is the url before the question mark).

So this url

```
http://localhost:xxxx/api/BindAppointmentResources?UserID=1
```

will, if no method with parameter name that match UserID are found, end up being routed to

```
http://localhost:xxxx/api/BindAppointmentResources
```

In the Get method you can still get the query string

```
var queryString = this.Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();
```

To prevent binding parameters from query string and only allow bindings from route values, you could remove the default QueryStringValueProviderFactory from the default HttpConfiguration configuration. Read more about it in this [article](http://www.strathweb.com/2013/04/asp-net-web-api-and-greedy-query-string-parameter-binding/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @marcus

Comment: I think I finally escape this problem by applying this solution :D

Comment: @RahulJyala Great!! If you are satisfied with the solution, please approve the answer :)

Comment: I have issues that my URL does not read #(Hash)  and showing the same result

Comment: @RahulJyala #(Hash) are used to search in the html document, not request a new document. Read here about it: https://blog.httpwatch.com/2011/03/01/6-things-you-should-know-about-fragment-urls/

Comment: so what the solution of this it seems like issue for me

Comment: but it did use # in API URL and gets result

Comment: I want to get rid of # in my API URL do you have something that can be helpful

Comment: I can access API if i use # in my URL but initially i didn't want this

Comment: @RahulJyala Basically, the only part that is sent to the api is localhost:xxxx/api/BindAppointmentResources because the browser doesn't transmit the hash part to the server

Comment: yes exactly but why not ? and I want error in that case if I use ## in my API URL do you have any solution ?

Comment: @RahulJyala The ? (query string) is designed to be sent to the server. You can't change that. This solution makes the web api ignore the query string.

Comment: @RahulJyala No problem. Have a nice day!